# Bind Crystal Reports with Dataset

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am having a form where I am updating data in my gridview and that updated gridview I want to save in one of the table on Save_Button_click; after that i want to generate report(crystal) for that sorted and updated data; there I got stuck ; Thanks in advance!

here is my query:

```
string StrAsset = "select * from tbl_Pre_Y1_Bus1,tbl_Pre_Y1_Bus_Master1_temp where tbl_Pre_Y1_Bus1.id='" + id + "' and tbl_Pre_Y1_Bus_Master1_temp.ID='" + ID + "')";
```

My Code:

```
{
dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("PartNo", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ChallanDate", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ChallanNo", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("sup_remark", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("sup_status", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("TMl_remark", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Tml_status", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Date_supp", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Sup_ins_name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("date_insp", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Inspectorname", typeof(string)));
}


     for (int i = 0; i < DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
         {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[12] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["sup_remark"].ToString();
            dr[13] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["sup_status"].ToString();
            dr[14] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TMl_remark"].ToString();
            dr[15] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Tml_status"].ToString();
            dr[16] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date_supp"].ToString();
            dr[17] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Sup_ins_name"].ToString();
            dr[18] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["date_insp"].ToString();
            dr[19] = DSAsset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Inspectorname"].ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

aspx code

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" HasCrystalLogo="False" runat="server"
                    AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" DisplayGroupTree="False"
                    EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" />
                <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
                    <Report FileName="Dispatch.rpt">
                    </Report>
                </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

how to resolve this problem:
it is not generating  report.

Comment: where is your crystal repost binding code?

Comment: post is edited now have a look